# Laravel doesn't work when I change server

Tags: php, laravel

I was working in my localhost with laravel 4, but when I migrate to a real work and I try to access to the website firefox return me the following webpage:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height;"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/ImageDocument.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resource://gre/res/TopLevelImageDocument.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://global/skin/media/TopLevelImageDocument.css"></link>
   <title>

     login (Imagen JPEG, 1920 × 1080 píxeles) - Escalad…

   </title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="shrinkToFit" width="908" height="511" src="public/login" alt="/public/login"></img>
  </body>
</html>
```

In order to migrate my website I did a tar with laravel files and copy to my server and then untar, and dump my mysql database and upload to the server.

Should I do anything more in order to migrate my website?

Edit: I am using route clousures, I haven't used controller, but the problem is that laravel doesn't enter in the route Login (neither others routes). In other words, despite inside routes I use localhost url's (I must change this in future, when I get that laravel enter in routes) laravel doesn't enter in any route, so I guess that maybe there is a especial config variable (set when create new project) that tell laravel how it must execute (I had been searching in config/app.php without luck)

Edit: Update with source code (I deleted irrelevant code from both)

My Login route:

```
Route::get('login', array( 'as' => 'login', 'before' => 'guest', function()
{
    $lang = substr(Request::header('Accept-Language'),0,2);
    App::setLocale($lang==NULL?'en':$lang);

    return View::make('login');
}));
```

And this is my login view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    {{ HTML::style('/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
    {{ HTML::style('/css/sign.css') }}
    <title>¡Entra!</title>

</head>
<!-- <body background={{ URL::asset('back1.png'); }}> -->
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="dlogin">
            <div class="hdivider"></div>
                <h1>{{ Lang::get('login.login' )}}</h1>
                @if (Session::has('flash_error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a> {{ Session::get('flash_error') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                @if (Session::has('flash_success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a> {{ Session::get('flash_success') }}
                    </div>
                @endif

                @if (Session::has('flash_notice'))
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a> {{ Session::get('flash_notice') }}
                    </div>
                @endif


                {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'method' => 'POST')) }}
                {{ Form::text('nick','', array('class' => 'form-control form', 'placeholder' => Lang::get('login.nick' ))) }}
                {{ Form::password('pass', array('class' => 'form-control form', 'placeholder' => Lang::get('login.password' ))) }}
                {{Form::submit(Lang::get('login.enter' ), ['class' => 'cbutton'])}}
                {{ Form::close() }}
                {{ Lang::get('login.notAccount' )}} {{ HTML::link('/crear_cuenta', Lang::get('login.register' )) }} {{ Lang::get('login.free' )}}
                {{ HTML::link('/password/remind', "¿Has olvidado tu contraseña?" ) }}
            <div class="hdivider"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
    {{ HTML::script('/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: laravel is working.... post your routes file. and the layout.

Comment: Updated my answer with that information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

The problem was a set of things.

First I need to update php in my server and then I have to configure mod_rewrite in apache.

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what have you changed in Laravel is hard to say but a simple guess who be that you didnt have changed the paths inside controllers, config etc etc?

Comment: I am using route clousures, I haven't used controller, but the problem is that laravel doesn't enter in the route Login (neither others routes). In other words, despite inside routes I use localhost url's (I must change this in future, when I get that laravel enter in routes) laravel doesn't enter in any route, so I guess that maybe there is a especial config variable (set when create new project) that tell laravel how it must execute (I had been searching in config/app.php without luck)

Comment: Maybe, i am not familiar with Laravel so saying anything more might hurt you more than it helps. It should be simple i think thought, take a good look at your code with a cup of tea :)